# Firefox for Android (v18) CSS Reset?

Tags: android, firefox, css

I'm struggling to remove unwanted box shadows and gradients from elements such as including `<input type="text">`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, and `<button>` in the latest version of [Firefox for Android](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/) (v18). The desktop counterpart of Firefox for Ubuntu and Windows **does not** exhibit the same issue.

Safari on iOS also adds styling to make certain elements appear more *native-like*, however resetting the unwanted styles was fairly easy thanks to `-webkit-appearance: none`.

[Mozilla's Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance) do mention support for `-moz-appearance: none`, however it does not seem to work as intended on Firefox for Android.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is well documented on bootstrap, removing the background image has worked for me

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8702

```
background-image: none;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

```
background:#fff;
border:0;
border-radius:0;
box-shadow:none;
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Override the Firefox-specific button background gradient e.g.:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
```